# Reading data from table into hash

Tags: perl

[image]

i want to read the data from table into hash and then split the value and price into array. 
for example:
Then i want to filter with user input the add the price. 
if user selected accessories1 then I want to read the value of accessories that is 001 and then get the price of 001 which is 10.

All coding is done in perl

Appreciate if someone gives me some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You have clearly explained exactly what you want, and it sounds trivial. What have you tried that doesn't work? What is causing you a problem?

Comment: please dont vote my question down...iam learning perl...i thought will get some ideas from here...

Comment: I don't think I voted you down. I'm happy to help people learn, but you didn't give any indication of having tried anything yourself. As I said, it seems like a fairly trivial thing to do in "raw perl" even without the TableContentParser mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/09/17/perlcookbook.html

"Use the HTML::TableContentParser module from CPAN:

```
use HTML::TableContentParser;

$tcp = HTML::TableContentParser->new;
$tables = $tcp->parse($HTML);

foreach $table (@$tables) {
  @headers = map { $_->{data} } @{ $table->{headers} };
  # attributes of table tag available as keys in hash
  $table_width = $table->{width};

  foreach $row (@{ $tables->{rows} }) {
    # attributes of tr tag available as keys in hash
    foreach $col (@{ $row->{cols} }) {
      # attributes of td tag available as keys in hash
      $data = $col->{data};
    }
  }
}
```

"